# Minimum sum of all elements in an array called array cost

Tags: arrays

Given an array [2,4,6,7]. We need to choose one number x.  Over iterating entire array we need to assign the new values a[i]=a[i]/x.
In the above scenario they choose 2.

The result array is [1,2,3,7]
The array cost is 1+2+3+7=13.

How can we choose an element randomly?

Answer (score -1):

There is a module in python called
`random` and that module has a function `random.choice(<array>)`

so the code would be :

`array = [2, 4, 6, 7]`

`x = random.choice(array)`

`for i in range(len(array))`

`array[i] /= x`